# find contiguous responses greater than x

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the the point at which participants reach 8 contiguous responses in a row that are greater than 3. For example:

```
x <- c(2,2,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,7)
```

i want to return the value 10.

i tried the code (Thanks @DWin):

```
which( rle(x)$values>3 & rle(x)$lengths >= 8)
sum(rle(x)$lengths[ 1:(min(which(rle(x)$lengths >= 8))-1) ]) + 8
```

the problem with the above code is that it only works if the responses are all identical and greater than 3. thus the code returns a zero.

if:

```
x <- c(2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,7)
```

the code works fine. but this isn't how my data looks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a new vector that contains the identical values that `rle` needs to work properly? You can use `ifelse()` for this and put everything into a function:

```
FUN <- function(x, value, runlength) {
  x2 <- ifelse(x > value, 1, 0)

  ret <- sum(rle(x2)$lengths[ 1:(min(which(rle(x2)$lengths >= runlength))-1) ]) + runlength
  return(ret)
}

> FUN(x, value = 3, runlength = 8)
[1] 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just convert your data so that the responses are only coded discriminating the measure of interest (greater than 3) and then your code will work as it is replacing x with x1.

```
x1 <- ifelse( x > 3, 4, 0 )
```

But if I was already doing this I might rewrite the code slightly more clearly this way.

```
runl <- rle(x1)
i <- which( runl$length > 8 & runl$value > 3 )[1]
sum( runl$length[1:(i-1)] ) + 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized way of doing it with just `cumsum` and `cummax`. Let's take an example that has a short (less than length 8) sequence of elements greater than 3 as well as a long one, just to make sure it's doing the right thing.

```
> x <- c(2,2,4,5,6,7,2,2,4,9,8,7,6,5,4,5,6,9,2,2,9)
> x3 <- x > 3
> cumsum(x3) - cummax(cumsum(x3)*(!x3))
 [1]  0  0  1  2  3  4  0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  0  0  1
> which( cumsum(x3) - cummax(cumsum(x3)*(!x3)) == 8)[1]
[1] 16
```